# Не отправляются данные с формы, перебрасывает на содержимое post.php

Tags: php, html

Подскажите пожалуйста.
С php раньше никогда не работала. Написала свой первый файл-обработчик формы, но с ошибками, не пойму где((

Вот форма

```
  <form action="./post.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="sbtn col-md-12 text-center">
                        <input class="name form-input" type="text" placeholder="NAME" name="name">
                        <input class="email form-input" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL" name="email">
                        <input class="email form-input" type="phone" placeholder="PHONE" name="phone">
                        <input class="message form-input" type="text" placeholder="MASSAGE" name="message">
                        <input type="hidden" name="uri" value="'<php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="site" value="'<php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>'">
                        <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="SEND">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Вот .php файл

```
<?PHP
//-------------------//
$adminemail="ksu_dp@ua.fm";
$sender="___";
$subject="Новая заявка! ____";
$backurl="_______";
//------------------------------------
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$msg=$_POST['message'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$source=
$uri=$_POST['uri'];
$site=$_POST['site'];

//--------------------------------//

  mail("$adminemail", "Отправитель: \n $sender", "Тема: \n $subject", "Имя: \n $name", "Телефон: \n $phone", "Источник: \n $source", "Сайт: \n $site", "Страница входа: \n $uri");


//------------------//
print "<script language='Javascript'><!--
function reload() {location = \"$backurl\"}; setTimeout('reload()', 3000);
//--></script>


<p>Thank you for leaving the application. We will call you soon!</p>";
exit;

?>
```

Перебрасывает на содержимое файла post.php при нажатии на submit. И на указанный email ничего не приходит

Спасибо если кто подскажет

Comment: Что значит "перебрасывает"? В форме указан post.php, значит этот файл должен обрабатывать запрос и он должен быть в адресной строке браузера после обработки.

Comment: также на указанный email не приходят данные

Comment: Приведённый .php это именно post.php? И он на сервере в том же каталоге, где и файл с формой?

Comment: Да, все в том же каталоге

Comment: Вы хотели сказать, выдаётся содержимое этого файла вместо результата его выполнения?

Comment: Да-да, сейчас подкорректирую свой вопрос, чтоб поточнее было

Comment: Тогда дело в настройках сервера. Нужно знать какой сервер используете и смотреть его конфигурационные файлы.

Comment: а сам php файл правильно написан?

Comment: ну в принципе файл вроде рабочий

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Функция `mail();` имеет прототип

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] );
```

У вас параметры не совсем соответствуют.

По поводу работы вашего сценария, а где вы его запускаете? На хостинге или локальном сервере? Бывает, что хостинг не поддерживает отправку почты (особенно часто это на бесплатных).

Comment: Названий классов "с пробелами" не существует. Элементу можно задать несколько классов и все они пишутся через пробел. `exit` - это конструкция, такая же, как и `echo` или `print` и допускает синтаксис без круглых скобок. В общем, вам бы немного подучить "мат.часть", прежде, чем давать советы другим.

Comment: @Dionis да, насчет классов я не точно выразился.

Comment: print я точно исправила, спасибо:)) за правильный синтаксис того или другого говорить не буду, потому что сегодня в первый раз все это вижу и пытаюсь поиспользовать. И да, на бесплатном хостинге пытаюсь запустить

Comment: @KsuLyguta насчет `print` я ошибся. Можно использовать как со скобками, так и без. Так же как и `exit;`.

Comment: понято, спасибо